# How to get the two lines(head+filtered content) as output with a simple command?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to get the head as in my output.

```
ps  lax |head -n 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
```

And the filtered line:

```
ps  lax |grep openbox |grep -v grep
0  1000  1608  1513  20   0 206408 20580 SyS_po S    ?          0:00 openbox --config-file /home/debian9/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
```

What i expect to get is as below two lines:

```
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000  1608  1513  20   0 206408 20580 SyS_po S    ?          0:00 openbox --config-file /home/debian9/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
```

How to get the two lines(head+filtered content) as output with a simple command?

Comment: See the updated answer, in regards to your edit, try `printf` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compound conditions you use awk, not grep:

```
ps  lax | awk 'NR==1 || /[o]penbox/'
```

Note the idiomatic use of `[o]` in @Cyrus and my answers so that the regexp doesn't match on this command itself so you don't need to explicitly remove this command name from with regexp.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps lax | grep -e '^F' -e '[o]penbox'
```

or

```
ps lax | grep '^F\|[o]penbox'
```

Comment: IMHO it is a bit restrictive to distinguish the first line by some of its contents (in this case matching an 'F' at the beginning). For instance, ```ps``` output and columns varies greatly from a system to another, or even by our own selection of columns. I'd suggest going for a more general solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The following circumvents the problem because the first line does not begin with a number: `ps lax | grep '^[^0-9]\|[o]penbox`

Answer (score 1):

Ed's answer using `awk` plus the `NR==1` condition is the best solution.

For completeness, let me show the use of `tee` and [*processs substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) with `>(command)`.

For instance: to display current processes (with `ps`) other than *bash* while retaining the `ps` header line, use `tee` in the following way:

```
$ ps | tee >(sed -n 1p) >(sed 1d | grep -v bash) > /dev/null
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     5782    2514    3792       1940  cons2    1415878 12:21:38 /usr/bin/ps
     9998       2    9708       9708  ?        1415878 12:38:41 /usr/bin/ssh-agent
$
```

Here `tee` redirects the output to two processes:

- one to display the first line (first `sed -n 1p`),
- then other that filters the first line (the other  `sed  1d`) and does an additional filtering with `grep`.

Finally, to prevent `tee` from dumping the original `ps` output, stdout is redirected to `/dev/null`